# Excel Trend line (SLOPE() ) and CORREL() yields different coefficients

Tags: excel, regression, correlation

I'm trying to use excel to get the coefficient for two financial market spreads using two methods on data series Sprd1 against data series Sprd2:

1) I used scatter plot and simply added a trend line, showing R^2 (0.4052) and Coefficient (0.614). Trend line should be using SLOPE() to get the coefficient...

2) I used =CORREL(Sprd1, Sprd2), showing 0.637; =RSQ(Sprd1, Sprd2), yielding 0.4052.

I understand that the R-sq values should be pretty close. But why would the coefficents differ? I'm trying to look for any difference in terms of excel's embedded methods or assumptions on the trendline and the CORREL.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

While both `RSQ` and `CORREL` work from the same equation

[image: pearson equation]

the value returned by `RSQ` is the square of that result.
i.e. `RSQ()=CORREL()^2`

`SLOPE`, on the other hand, does not use **(y-MEAN(y))^2**, nor does it take a square root of the denominator:
[image: SLOPE function]

so will give slightly different results, depending on the mean of y